# August 2019 NDK 64 bit requirement Intel binary

Tags: android, android-ndk, 64-bit, x86-64

As native Android developer I looking for info about latest Google requirements for my Android apps.
One of them is from blog post

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

> **In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.**

Now I have x86 libraries in my app. It's no problem to add x86_64 version, but

1. I never saw Intel 64 bit smartphone/tablet available.
2. Intel looks like soon to be dropped like MIPS from NDK. There are still some Zenfones from 2016 somebody may use, so that's why I have x86 in my apk.

The question is what is the most correct way to support Google new requirement about 64-bit? Do I need Intel 64 bit if I have 32 bit binary or ARM64 only is enough?

What about apk size? The more binaries I have the larger my apk is. And now it's already ~98MB. Maximum size is 100MB. So if we forced to add 64 bit, will maximum apk size be also increased? Or I need to create apk per platform?

Comment: My interpretation: If you plan on continuing to include x86 libraries with your app, then you'll also have to include x86_64 versions of those libraries. If you drop x86, then there's no requirement for you to include x86_64 versions.

Comment: Whether you want to have a single APK or [multiple APKs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits) is up to you. Both are possible.

Comment: By far, x86 and x86_64 are only for emulators. You really don’t have to include these 2 ABIs. For now, it should be fine only adding armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a using abiFilters.

Comment: If you care about APK size (and you should, regardless of this policy, your users will thank you) you should not be distributing a fat APK. It looks like [app bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) make avoiding this quite easy.

Comment: @shizhen At least Asus Zenfone 2 has Intel CPU. I included x86 binaries to make my app work faster on such devices. armv7 will work in emulation mode, which is slower.

Comment: @DanAlbert Thank You, I will try to setup those app bundles for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use new [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) as optimal solution. APK per platform are created automatically, so it doesn't matter if Intel 64 bit included or not.

Comment: even when I use the Android App Bundle, The message (In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.) still appear whenever I upload App bundle to Google Play